# Error in mysqli statement

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli, mysql-python, mysql-error-1064

I got this error in mysqli

> mysqli_select_db() expects exactly 2 parameters, 1 given in
>   /home/u751513549/public_html/recent.php on line 6

This is the code

```
<?php // Connects to your Database 
mysqli_connect("localhost", "u751513549_liker", "xxxxxxxx") or die(mysqli_error());
mysqli_select_db("u851654599_liker") or die(mysqli_error());
$data = mysqli_query("SELECT * 
                      FROM token_all
                      ORDER BY RAND() LIMIT 0,9; ") or die(mysqli_error());
Print "<table";
while ($info = mysqli_fetch_array($data)) {
    Print "<tr>";
    Print " <a href=\"https://www.facebook.com/" . $info['id'] . "/\"/> <img  src=\"https://graph.facebook.com/" . $info['id'] . "/picture\"/></a>";
}
Print "</table>";
```

Please help me to fix this error I am a beginner.

Comment: Try removing the semicolon.

Answer (score 1):

Try this (I have added another parameter to `mysqli_select_db`):

```
$con = mysqli_connect("localhost", "u751513549_liker", "xxxxxxxx") or die(mysqli_error($con));    
mysqli_select_db($con, "u851654599_liker") or die(mysqli_error($con));
```

Answer (score 0):

Step 1: Create Connection

```
$conn = mysqli_connect("localhost","u751513549_liker","xxxxxxxx","u851654599_liker");
```

Step 2: Run your Query

```
$query= mysqli_query($conn,"Your Query") or die(mysqli_error($conn));
```

Step 3 : Fetch records

```
$result = mysqli_fetch_all($query);
```

Step 4 : Display Records

```
var_dump($result);
```